# How to put keyframes at particular time in FLV Video?

Tags: video, conversion, editing, encoding, flv

I want to encode an existing FLV video to another FLV Video with resize + croping. Existing video has iFrames at required positions. Now which encoder software is best suited use for this task.

Thanks, Sunny.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Commercial product: [Moyea FLV Editor Ultimate](http://www.moyea.com/flv-editor-ultimate) $49.95 with trial version.

> You can trim FLV, merge FLV, split
>   FLV, replace FLV audio, add metadata
>   and cue point，save project file for
>   future editing, transform MP3 to
>   lossless FLV, etc. It generates HTML/
>   SWF (with various player skins,
>   special effects, and preloaders) for
>   uploading to website and blog.
>
> You can import MP3 and FLV files
>   encoded with H.264, H.263, Flash 8,
>   Flash 8 with alpha, Sorenson Spark,
>   Nellymoser, etc. and export FLV, SWF,
>   and HTML without any loss of quality.
>   You can take it as an FLV joiner, FLV
>   splitter, FLV cutter, FLV trimmer, FLV
>   to lossless SWF converter, and MP3 to
>   lossless FLV converter.

Comment: Tell me if there is any free one.

Comment: No luck with it. It is useless.

Comment: Moyea products are normally excellent. Could you please explain why is it useless?

Comment: Hi harrymc, demo of this product is not working. It can't export flv.

Comment: It says that it has exported flv but when I see output, There is not file with that name.

Comment: I tried it also and didn't manage to make it work. Here is an older version of this product - FLV Editor Pro - at http://www.flvsoft.com/flv_editor/. This one works. Just import the flv, click on it, then set clipping and cropping on the right, apply all button, then export the result.